# iOS camera and audio API differences between iPad Mini and Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, simulator

I'm working on an hibrid iOS app , and the xcode simulator doesn't have audio or video ( webcam ) so the only way to test it will be having a real device , I'm trying to figure out if and IPad Mini 4 could be enough and not different in the API calls ( webrtc) to enable the camera to stream , or should better buy an iPhone for testing , thinking on an ipad because I can use it for other things too

Also how you do if you want to test iOS 10 and iOS 11 in the same device a downgrade could be possible , or also the only way is having another device just testing a lower version of iOS

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPAD Mini 4 should enough for your need, and most of the API will capability all current iOS devices (64bit) 
However, if you want future proof, kindly thing about the device that have ARKit (iPAD Pro)as the trend of the development.

It better with two separated device for iOS10 / iOS11 as Testing for Commerce software, as iOS device don't allow downgrade.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH17-SW1